# Call method in a running activity from a service

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am currently working on a Android project.

So far,  I have implemented Firebase, in particular the FirebaseInstanceIdService and the FirebaseMessagingService:

```
public class FirebaseIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {
private static final String TAG = "FirebaseIDService";

private Context context;

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    context = getApplicationContext();
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.e(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("token", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("token", refreshedToken);
    editor.commit();

    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}

/**
 * Persist token to backend.
 * @param token The new token.
 */
private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    SendRegistrationKey task = new SendRegistrationKey(context);
    task.execute(token);
}
```

}

```
public class MessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

private static final String TAG = "MsgService";

/**
 * Called when message is received.
 *
 * @param remoteMessage Object representing the message received from Firebase Cloud Messaging.
 */
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.e(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        sendNotification(remoteMessage);
    }

    // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
    // message, here is where that should be initiated. See sendNotification method below.
}
// [END receive_message]

private void sendNotification(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    RemoteMessage.Notification notification = remoteMessage.getNotification();
    PushNotificationManager PNManager = PushNotificationManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    PNManager.buildNotification(notification.getTitle(), notification.getBody());
}
```

**What I want to achieve is the following:**

When the App is in background, I just want to have a simple notification in the notification center. (This is already working)

BUT, when the app is in foreground and currently running, I want to have a different behaviour:
I want to consume the push notification and show an alert instead.

But my question is: how can I interact with the running activity from the service or what is the correct way to achieve the intended behaviour?
Ther must be a simple soultion, right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: sendBroadcast from the Service, And in the Activity listen for the broadcast

Answer (score 5, accepted):

write this code in application class

```
 public Context currentactvity = null;
public Context getCurrentactvity() {
    return currentactvity;
}

public void setCurrentactvity(Context currentactvity) {
    this.currentactvity = currentactvity;
}
```

write this code in each activity onresume method and in onpause method set null

```
 // in onresume
MyApplication.getInstance().setCurrentactvity(this);

// in onpause
MyApplication.getInstance().setCurrentactvity(null);
```

now you can call activity method from service class

```
  if (MyApplication.getInstance().getCurrentactvity() != null && MyApplication.getInstance().getCurrentactvity() instanceof youractivityname) {
            ((youractivityname) MyApplication.getInstance().getCurrentactvity()).youmethodname(parameter);

        }
```

Comment: That's great, that was what I was looking for (y)

Answer (score 2):

> how can I interact with the running activity from the service or what is the correct way to achieve the intended behaviour?

The best way would be simply to use Event Bus (i.e. [GreenRobot's](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/) or [local broadcast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html)). Your activity registers listener in `onResume()` (and deregisters in `onPause()`) and your service simply broadcasts the message when times comes.

The main benefit is that you keep both elements (service and activity) completely separated. You also avoid worst possible solution - calling Activity's methods directly.

To find out when you are in background or not, it's best to utilis Application's [GreenRobot's](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html)[ActivityLifecycleCallbacks](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html)  - there's no point of forcing activities to report that as there's completely no benefit from that.

Answer (score 1):

try with this:

This method check for all running apps, and return true or false whether current app is in background state or in foreground state.

```
    public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
        boolean isInBackground = true;
        ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
            for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
                if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                    for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                        if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                            isInBackground = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
            ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
            if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                isInBackground = false;
            }
        }

        return isInBackground;
    }
```

Comment: above mothod check for running apps, and return true or false whether current app is in background state or in foreground state

Comment: which info and where?

Answer (score 0):

Try

**1.** Register custom broadcast receiver in your activity

```
context.registerReceiver (myBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter ("CUSTOM_ACTION"));
private final BroadcastReceiver myBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver () {

    @Override
    public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {

        //Do something
    }
};
```

**2.** Send broadcast from your service

```
Intent intent = new Intent ("CUSTOM_ACTION");
context.sendBroadcast (intent)
```

Comment: +1.  Thanks for the update. Updated the answer.      
"Create the receiver at runtime by calling Context.registerReceiver(), instead of declaring the receiver in the manifest."       
https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background.html#broadcasts