# Android Notify Listview BaseAdapter from IntentService

Tags: android, listview, intentservice

I have a listview which extends BaseAdapter. I would like to call notifyDataSetChanged() method to refresh the listview from the IntentService! Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: using localBrodcast MAnager

Comment: Thanks but what if I have 3 listviews and refresh it based on the listview which is visible to the user!

Comment: is your listviews in same activity?

Comment: No different activities

Comment: then inyour service check which activity is currently showing. or you can use same localbrodcat manager for all activity, which activity is open that activity get brodcast

Comment: So then how to know which activity is open or is in foreground?

Comment: check my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/43391993/6756514

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can register a `LocalBroadcastReceiver` in your `Activity` or `Fragment` (or even in your `Adapter` though I wouldn't recommend) and update your `List` on `Broadcast` received. Detailed explanation with example and code snippets are Here:

https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/report-status.html

P.S: Though I really recommend using `AsyncTask` if your operation is related to the `View` that **user** is **interacting** with. `IntentService` is usually used when you need to run an operation that exists and works even after `View` is destroyed.